# Adding an External link in flash notice rails controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller

I know this is simple but I need to add an external link to a rails controller flash notice. Right now I have this

```
redirect_to root_path, flash[:success] = "Complete this quick survey. <a href='#{'http://google.com'}'>Click here</a>".html_safe
```

And I keep getting the error

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):
```

What is the proper syntax?

I am using ruby 2.2.1p85 & Rails 4.0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without the interpolation.It will work.

```
redirect_to root_path, flash[:success] = "Complete this quick survey. <a href='https://www.google.com'>Click here</a>".html_safe
```

or if you want to interpolate:

```
url = "https://www.google.com"
redirect_to root_path, flash[:success] = "Complete this quick survey. <a href='#{url}'>Click here</a>".html_safe
```

Comment: I am using ruby 2.2.1p85 & Rails 4.0.10